# How can I debug this transpilation problem in webpack? It disappears if I set minimize to false

Tags: javascript, django, reactjs, webpack

I'm developing a django application with a reactjs front end that uses webpack for hot serving of javascript during development. Versions are pretty much all the latest:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.2.3",
    "@babel/core": "^7.4.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread": "^7.4.0",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-jsx": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.4.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.4.2",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "ajv": "^6.10.0",
    "auto-bind": "^1.2.1",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.5",
    "bluebird": "^3.5.1",
    "chai": "^4.2.0",
    "chai-as-promised": "^7.1.1",
    "chart.js": "^2.8.0",
    "css-loader": "^2.1.1",
    "d3": "^5.9.2",
    "deep-equal": "^1.0.1",
    "enzyme": "^3.9.0",
    "file-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "fusioncharts": "^3.13.4",
    "history": "^4.9.0",
    "immutability-helper": "^2.9.1",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "jquery.cookie": "^1.4.1",
    "js-yaml": "^3.13.0",
    "jsdom": "^14.0.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.11",
    "mocha": "^4.1.0",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "query-string": "^5.1.1",
    "react": "^16.8.5",
    "react-addons-update": "^15.6.2",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.31.5",
    "react-codemirror": "^1.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.5",
    "react-dropzone": "^4.3.0",
    "react-fusioncharts": "^1.0.5",
    "react-hot-loader": "^3.1.3",
    "react-input-autosize": "^2.2.1",
    "react-numeric-input": "^2.2.3",
    "react-popper": "^0.8.3",
    "react-redux": "^6.0.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-select": "^2.4.2",
    "react-sortable-hoc": "^1.8.3",
    "react-table": "^6.9.2",
    "react-tooltip": "^3.10.0",
    "reconnecting-websocket": "^4.1.10",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "redux-form": "^8.1.0",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "select2": "^4.0.6-rc.1",
    "style-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "sunburst-chart": "^1.3.1",
    "url-loader": "^1.1.2",
    "uuid": "^3.3.2",
    "webpack": "^4.29.6",
    "webpack-bundle-tracker": "^0.3.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.2.1"
  }
```

During development with the hot server running, everything works as expected. If I switch to production mode and use the main.js file which builds without warnings or error, The code fails in the browser with "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (" on this area of the main.js:

```
    "function"!=typeof Object.assign&&(Object.assign=function(e){"use strict";var t,n,r,o;if(null==e)throw new TypeError("Cannot convert undefined or null to object");for(t
/*! dontAppend && */a.canvas&&a.canvas.appendChild(t),o.node=o[0]=t,t.raphael=!0,t.raphaelid=o.id=e._oid++,o.matrix=e.matrix(),o.realPath=null,o.attrs=o.attrs||{},o.fol
/** !
 * @license FusionCharts JavaScript Library
 * Copyright FusionCharts Technologies LLP
 * License Information at <http://www.fusioncharts.com/license>
 */
var r={name:"default",theme:{base:{chart:{labelDisplay:"stagger !important",caption:"Theme Caption \\!important",canvasBgColor:"#56EF22",borderThickness:"5 !important",
/** !
 * @license FusionCharts JavaScript Library
 * Copyright FusionCharts Technologies LLP
 * License Information at <http://www.fusioncharts.com/license>
 *
 * @version //? write(JSON.parse(require('fs').readFileSync('./package.json')).version);
 */
function(e,t){if("function"!=typeof t&&null!==t)throw new TypeError("Super expression must either be null or a function, not "+typeof t);e.prototype=Object.create(t&&t.
```

"function" looks strange. In order to debug this, I turned the minimization off in the webpack config but when I do so the error disappears and the resulting (rather large) main.js works fine.

Any help on how to debug the problem further (or solve it) much appreciated. The full production and development configurations are as follows:

base.js:

```
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  context: __dirname,
  entry: '../assets/js/main',

  output: {
      path: path.resolve('./assets/bundles/'),
      filename: "main.js"},

  plugins: [],

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js(|x)$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader'}},
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']},
      {
        test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg|otf|gif)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
        use: ['file-loader']
      },
      {
        test: /\.woff(2)?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
        use: ['url-loader']
      }]},

  resolve: {
    modules: ['assets/js', 'node_modules'],
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: '../assets/bundles/',
    hot: true,
    headers: {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'}}};
```

local.js (working fine):

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const BundleTracker = require('webpack-bundle-tracker');

const config = require('./base.js');

// Use webpack dev server
config.mode = 'development';
config.entry = [
  'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3000',
  'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
  '../assets/js/main'];

// override django's STATIC_URL for webpack bundles
config.output.publicPath = 'http://localhost:3000/assets/bundles/';

// Add HotModuleReplacementPlugin and BundleTracker plugins
config.plugins = config.plugins.concat([
  new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
  //new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
  new BundleTracker({filename: './webpack-stats.json'})]);

module.exports = config;
```

production.js (not working):

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const BundleTracker = require('webpack-bundle-tracker');

const config = require('./base.js');

config.mode = 'production';
config.plugins = config.plugins.concat([
  new BundleTracker({filename: './webpack-stats-prod.json'}),

  // removes a lot of debugging code in React
  new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    'process.env': {
      'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production')
  }}),

  // keeps hashes consistent between compilations
  new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin()
]);

module.exports = config;
```

Comment: `on this line of the main.js` - that seems to be a very short line - minified code usually has very long lines - are you sure you're reading the error correctly? Also, it could be something to do with the previous line - what does the code for that line look like in the unminified version? Surely you can find `Super expression must either be null or a function` in the unminified source

Comment: Sorry, it is a very long line but I felt I'd included the pertinent part. "Super expression must either be null or a function" is not in my source.

Comment: Ok, so what's in that very long line just BEFORE the code you posted

Comment: It was hard to copy paste because it overflows the limits. I've pasted it above truncated to 168 chars per line. Hope this helps.

Comment: so, ignoring comments (why are there comments in minified code) `var r={name:"default",theme:{base:{chart:{labelDisplay:"stagger !important",caption:"Theme Caption \\!important",canvasBgColor:"#56EF22",borderThickness:"5 !important",function(e,t){if("function"!=t ...` it's clear that there's an object being initialised (`var r = {`) when suddenly there's this function introduced where a `key` or `property name` is expected - so, the minifier is broken, it's outputting comments for a start!

Comment: The minifier more than halves the size of main.js but I agree it is strange that it appears to include some comments (especially duplicating them) - perhaps that is something to do with licensing. As the hot serving of the code works fine, it is safe to assume that the minifier introduces this error. FWIW the charts display correctly in the hot served version. I still have no idea how to address this issue. It was introduced many (>50) commits ago but was not present in the upgraded release so something in our code 'exposes' the issue.

Comment: still - it's clear the problem is `var r = {key: value, function() {...} }`, which is invalid, where it should possibly be `var r = {key: value, key2: function() {...} }`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191951/discussion-between-paul-whipp-and-jaromanda-x).